# Can you have a private attribute which type is an Interface?

Tags: java, interface, private

In our code we are supposed to have an `Interface` (let's call it `InterfaceMap`) that has the methods that let you put a cell in a Sheet (putCell(), getCell(), etc).

We have a class called `OurSheetMatrix` that implements that InterfaceMap. Can we have something on a different class `Sheet` like:

```
public class Sheet {
  private InterfaceMap m = new OurSheetMatrix();
  ...
}
```

I think we might be able to do this not with Interfaces, but with abstract classes. But now, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `OurSheetMatrix` [is-a](http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/%27is_a%27_relationship_and_a_%27has_a%27_relationship_in_Java) `InterfaceMap`. You could not however say `new InterfaceMap();` because you can not [instantiate](http://www.javaying.com/2006/10/class-instantiation.html) an interface directly (It's probably best to think of them as promises [or more formally contracts]). Abstract classes are similar but distinct, it's the relationship that matters (and they can't be directly instantiated).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it :)

```
private InterfaceMap m = new OurSheetMatrix();
```

is OK. You can also pass references to your interface around in methods:

```
public void doSomething(InterfaceMap iamp) {
  //Do something with an InterfaceMap. 
  //I don't know (or care) exactly what class it is, 
  //so long as it implements InterfaceMap
}
```

But if you have something more specific:

```
public void doSomethingElse(OurSheetMatrix matrix) {}
```

It cannot be called like this:

```
InterfaceMap imap = new OurSheetMatrix();  //this is OK
doSomethingElse(imap);                     //But this? NO! can't do this!
```

The above call to `doSomethingElse` would not compile because `doSomethingElse` wants a `OurSheetMatrix`. Although we know it's really a `OurSheetMatrix` the method does not know.

All `OneSheetMatrix` objects are also `InterfaceMap`s, but `InterfaceMap`s *are not necessarily* `OneSheetMatrix` objects, hence the call to `doSomethingElse` is not valid - there may be other classes which implement `InterfaceMap`.